# Issues facing with Talend BD 5.6 Integration with Hortonworks Sandbox 2.1 or Cloudera 5.2

Tags: hdfs, bigdata, sqoop, talend, hortonworks-data-platform

I have downloaded Talend Open Studio v5.6 Big Data Version and Hortonworks Sandbox 2.1 and Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.2 and able to interact with and upload data to both HDP and CDH through their Hue interface. But, when I am trying to use the Talend components to make data transfer to HDFS from an Oracle RDBMS, I am getting stuck at different phases which I am listing below.

I am using VM manager as Oracle Virtual Box and could only use NAT as network configuration as other configurations are disallowed in my organization for security reasons.

**Exhibit 1: Using tSqoop/tHDFS component to transfer data to HDFS{Hortonworks Sandbox 2.1}**

I am using below configuration

```
NameNode URI: "hdfs://127.0.0.1:8020"
ResourceManager: "127.0.0.1:8032"*
```

**Error with tSqoop:**

```
  [ERROR]: org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool - Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host; Host Details : local host is: "PTP-A4A-020/10.206.8.142"; destination host is: "127.0.0.1":8032;
```

**Error with tHDFS:**

```
Exception in component tHDFSOutput_1

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/hue/sqoop-oracle/SCD_POC/STG_OVERD_LN.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

...
**Exhibit 2: Using tHive component to interact with Hive tables {Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.2}**
    *I am using hostname:"127.0.0.1" and port:"10000" and User:"hue"*

**Error:**

```
Exception in component tHiveConnection_1
java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to 127.0.0.1:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
```

However, when using the above NameNode and ResourceManager URI configurations, I am able to load data into HDFS {Cloudera} with tSqoopImport.

Answer (score 0):

I have it worked using "Host Only Adapter" configuration on virtual box -> Network. Basically it assigned a new IP address (type Class C) within default 10.0.2.15 and thus I can have my application (talend) communicate to NameNode or DataNode present in Cloudera VM.